# Can we set 2 different port for apache mysql port?

Tags: mysql, xampp

The default port for MySQL connection is 3306. But can we set 2 different port for it? Maybe port 30 and 3306, thus we can have connections at `localhost:30` and `localhost:3306`, assuming all ports are free. I try to run this using xampp in window 10.

Comment: For me the reason to do this is not clear. You can create as many databases in one mySQL server as you like. Thus it makes no sense to have two server on one machine, even not for testing purposes because your productive machine will have two different database server as a source.

Comment: AFAIK MySQL can't listen on two ports natively. But it should be possible to configure *port translation* in the OS. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790242/how-to-add-a-port-to-mysql-server) for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommend by mysql for good reasons.

> >
>   Warning
>
> > Normally, you should never have two servers that update data in the same databases. This may lead to unpleasant surprises if your operating system does not support fault-free system locking. If (despite this warning) you run multiple servers using the same data directory and they have logging enabled, you must use the appropriate options to specify log file names that are unique to each server. Otherwise, the servers try to log to the same files.
> >
> > Even when the preceding precautions are observed, this kind of setup works only with MyISAM and MERGE tables, and not with any of the other storage engines. Also, this warning against sharing a data directory among servers always applies in an NFS environment. Permitting multiple MySQL servers to access a common data directory over NFS is a very bad idea. The primary problem is that NFS is the speed bottleneck. It is not meant for such use. Another risk with NFS is that you must devise a way to ensure that two or more servers do not interfere with each other. Usually NFS file locking is handled by the lockd daemon, but at the moment there is no platform that performs locking 100% reliably in every situation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-data-directories.html

See here there you will find also, what you have to do

Comment: This warning is about **two** MySQL instances (physically) sharing the same data. The question is about **one** MySQL instance listening on two ports.